# Tensorflow: Use same dequeued batch at different locations in graph

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a working input pipeline that uses multiple threads to read data from tfrecords files, decodes and preprocesses the data, and serves them to the graph. I used [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception) example as a starting point. My problem is that I need the input batch again in the loss layer, to compute a reconstruction error of the input. If I now just add the dequeuing operation multiple times to my graph, i.e. once at the input layer and once at the loss layer, I obviously get two times a different batch since tensorflow evaluates the operation twice. What is the easiest way to overcome this?

Comment: If you need value twice in a single run call, connect to deque to `tf.identity` and reference `tf.identity` twice. If you need it in different run calls, save dequeued value to variable by running `tf.assign` and reference the variable

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for, this solves my problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you can try adding identity operation after dequeuing and connect other nodes to that identity operation.